# How to add missing spaces after periods using regex, without changing decimals

Tags: python, regex

I have a large piece of text that is missing spaces after some of the periods. However the text also contains decimal numbers.

Here's what I have so far to fix the problem using regex (I'm using python):

`re.sub(r"(?!\d\.\d)(?!\. )\.", '. ', my_string)`

But the first escape group doesn't seem to work. It still matches periods in decimal numbers.

Here is sample text to make sure any potential solution works:

```
this is a.match
this should also match.1234
and this should 123.match

this should NOT match. Has space after period
this also should NOT match 1.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\.(?!(?<=\d\.)\d) ?', '. ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG1Kua/1). The trailing space is matched optionally, so if it is there, it will be removed and put back.

*Details*

- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)` - do not match any further if the dot before was a dot between two digit
- `?` - an optional space.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zn4bVB):

```py
import re
text = "this is a.match\nthis should also match.1234\nand this should 123.match\n\nthis should NOT match. Has space after period\nthis also should NOT match 1.23"
print(re.sub(r'\.(?!(?<=\d\.)\d) ?', '. ', text))
```

Output:

```
this is a. match
this should also match. 1234
and this should 123. match

this should NOT match. Has space after period
this also should NOT match 1.23
```

Alternatively, use a `(?! )` lookahead as in your attempt:

```py
re.sub(r'\.(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)(?! )', '. ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG1Kua/2) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/55Chl9).

Comment: Works great thank you, can you elaborate why this part does what it does?:   (?!(?<=\d\.)\d)

Comment: @Idodo `(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if - immediately to the right of the current position - there is a digit that is immediately preceded with a digit and a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.. not sure if this is better or worse for performance than Wiktor's solution.

```
re.sub(r"(?!\d\.\d)(?!.\. )(.\.)(.)", r"\1 \2", my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt="hello world.this is boise idaho.a this is twin falls."
pattern=r"(\w+\s*\.\w+)+"
matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
for item in matches:
    front,back=item.split('.')
    replace=front+'. '+back
    txt=re.sub(item,replace,txt)
    
print(txt)

hello world. this is boise idaho. a this is twin falls.
```